# connecting bluetooth headphones keeps failing

Tags: audio, raspberry-pi, pulseaudio, bluetooth

I am trying to connect a pair of JBL JR310BT headphones to a raspberry pi zero, running Raspberry Pi OS based on buster. I receive similar messages as displayed in [this thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/258074/error-when-trying-to-connect-to-bluetooth-speaker-org-bluez-error-failed). I certainly tried all suggested solutions without success.
What was somewhat weird is that the `load-module` commands with pactl did produce the following:

```
Connection failure: Connection refused
pa_context_connect() failed: Connection refused
```

The pairing process does seem to work w/o problems and connects briefly. Then it disconnects and trying to do the `connect` command fails like so:

```bash
[bluetooth]# pair 84:D3:trus35:82:11
Device 84:D3: not available
[bluetooth]# pair 84:D3:trus35:82:11
Device 84:D3:52:35:82:11 not available
[CHG] Device 72:78:EC:BB:9B:26 RSSI: -50
[NEW] Device 84:D3:52:35:82:11 JBL JR310BT
[bluetooth]# pair 84:D3:trus35:82:11
[CHG] Device 84:D3:52:35:82:11 Trusted: yes
Changing 84:D3:52:35:82:11 trust succeeded
[bluetooth]# pair 84:D3:D3:52:35:82:11
Attempting to connect to 84:D3:52:35:82:11
[CHG] Device 84:D3:52:35:82:11 Connected: yes
[CHG] Device 84:D3:52:35:82:11 Modalias: bluetooth:v02B0p0000d001F
[CHG] Device 84:D3:52:35:82:11 UUIDs: 0000110b-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device 84:D3:52:35:82:11 UUIDs: 0000110c-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device 84:D3:52:35:82:11 UUIDs: 0000110e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device 84:D3:52:35:82:11 UUIDs: 0000111e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device 84:D3:52:35:82:11 UUIDs: 00001200-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device 84:D3:52:35:82:11 ServicesResolved: yes
Failed to connect: org.bluez.Error.Failed
[JBL JR310BT]# connect 84:D3:52:35:82:11
Attempting to connect to 84:D3:52:35:82:11
Failed to connect: org.bluez.Error.Failed
[CHG] Device 84:D3:52:35:82:11 ServicesResolved: no
[CHG] Device 84:D3:52:35:82:11 Connected: no
```

I've repeated the whole thing now a couple of times, tried rebooting, restarting, even reinstall pulseaudio. Still the same result.

One thing I repeatedly am notified is that my locales are somewhat messed up. Also a sticker on the headphones indicate "UK CA" - it's a stretch but could that somehow be related?
And maybe also important to know: I was already successful to pair other headphones (Anker Soundcore Life P2) to the pi...
Thanks for any help.